# Automatic transfer of IntelliJ settings among projects - How is it done?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ idea 2017.

I created my first project and gave it some settings for git, proxy and so on.

Now whenever i create a new project (not module) in a new folder on my system, all the settings are automatically transferred to this new project. I am wondering how IntelliJ handles the automatic copy of settings?

I don't click on import settings or import project. I just create a new project from scratch?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies for git settings, but generally, IntelliJ stores some settings in a workspace.xml file or similar. Those can also be used to sync the settings over multiple computers which has caused weird behaviour for me in the past. I would assume that IntelliJ just keeps your latest settings in a similar file as a template for a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a lot of the configuration, you have two scopes:

- Project
- IDE

With the project scope, the config is contained in xml files in the `.idea` folder of your project. With the IDE scope, the xml config files are outside the project, typically in the `~/.Idea2017` or `~\IntelliJIdea2017.3` (depending on version) folder. In both cases only the difference from the default settings are stored in the xml files.

The project scope is good for sharing settings among team members, as the xml config can be added to source control. If you have multiple projects, the IDE scope is better, since you can use the same settings across projects. Sadly, there is no good way of having both the same setting in multiple projects, and sharing the same settings among team members at the same time. (I have had to hack it using symlinks..)

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html for tips on how to share your IDE settings among team members and/or IDE instances

Comment: Thanks, but I've been through the whole settings repository thingy, but it just doesn't work in a satisfying degree.

Comment: @Tobb I can not find any such xml file. I am on Idea 2016. Can you share the location of your file?

Comment: It is probably a hidden folder, located in ~ (linux/osx), og c:\users\yourusername (windows). I actually see now that the file name varies a bit, on my home computer it was C:\Users\Tobb\.IdeaC2017 or something like that, on my Linux work computer it's ~/.IntelliJIdea2017.3. Updated my answer a bit.